# When I try to install Pycharm or Atom through Ubuntu software centre, I get the error: snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I've just tried installing atom and pycharm from the software center.

Here's what happened:

I was asked to register to Ubuntu One.
I was asked for authentication. Once the authentication was done, 
I typed in my system password.
I get this:

Detailed errors from the package manager follow:

**snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request**

Then I tried installing multiple software. Many of them like pycharm and atom were giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to install via software center, you will get error. I too had the same problem. Because they are snaps. You can install snaps as in the below article.

[How to install Snap packages on Ubuntu 16.04 | TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-snap-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04/)